# Python to Discord Webhook via requests module error 400

Tags: post, python-requests, discord, webhooks, praw

I'm trying to send posts from a subreddit to a discord webhook using the "praw" and "requests" module for python 3. I have the following method for the same,

```
def discordwebh(submission):
content = ""
image = ""
if "i.redd" in submission.url:
    image = submission.url
elif "i.imgur" in submission.url:
    image = submission.url
elif "v.redd" in submission.url:
    content = "Reddit Video : " + submission.url
else:
    content = "> " + submission.url + "\n" + submission.selftext[:1024]

data = {
    "username": "Spidey Bot",
    "content": "Check this out <@&999444449666614666>",
    "embeds": [
        {
            "author": {
                "name": str(submission.author),
                "url": "https://www.reddit.com/u/" + str(submission.author)
            },
            "title": str(submission.title),
            "url": "https://www.reddit.com" + str(submission.permalink),
            "description": content,
            "image": {
                "url": image
            }
        }
    ]
}

push = requests.post(url="https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xyz",
                     headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                     json={"text":json.dumps(data)})

return "[" + str(push.status_code) + "] Passing data " + str(submission.permalink) + " to Discord Webhook"
```

It does work most of the times. However, some posts cause it to return 400: Bad Request. How can I go about this issue? Is there are a way to make sure everything has been delimited in the body and this works universally across all posts.

Comment: https://github.com/NNTin/tracker-reddit-discord/blob/master/main.py use the discord library for sending your webhook. The problem you are probably running into is that your description body is too big. If you were using the discord library you'll see a bette error response.

Comment: Thanks, but even with that is it unavoidable?